# How sort json and sql request

Tags: php, sql

I have sql request

```
$sql = "SELECT * From questions q JOIN answer_options a_o ON q.id  = a_o.question_id  JOIN answer_test a_t ON a_o.answer_test_id  = a_t.answer_option_id";
```

The result of this request

```
[{"id":"1","questions_text":"Who you are ? ","answer_option":"Dog","question_id":"1","answer_test_id":"1","answer":"1","answer_option_id":"1"},
{"id":"1","questions_text":"What your car","answer_option":"Audi","question_id":"2","answer_test_id":"1","answer":"1","answer_option_id":"1"},
{"id":"1","questions_text":"Who you are ?","answer_option":"Cat","question_id":"1","answer_test_id":"1","answer":"1","answer_option_id":"1"}]
```

But i want for him to be

```
[{"id":"1","questions_text":"Who you are ? ","answer_option":"Dog", "Cat","question_id":"1","answer_test_id":"1","answer":"1","answer_option_id":"1"},
{"id":"1","questions_text":"What your car","answer_option":"Audi","question_id":"2","answer_test_id":"1","answer":"1","answer_option_id":"1"},
```

Comment: Add `LIMIT 2` to the end of your query.

Comment: see the difference in the first line in my two variants in the parameter "answer_option"

Answer (score 0):

How about if you solve the problem with SQL and PHP (or the language you want).
First, you can add to your SQL request "order by questions_text", so all the rows with same question comes next to eachother.
Then on php, you can create a *$tempQuestion* variable which checks if the question is changed. Something like this:

```
$tempQuestion="";
for(){ //loop the result of your SQL request
   if(['questions_text'] == $tempQuestion){//the question remains the same
   //do what you gotta do...
   } else { //the question is changed
   //do the other thing...
   }
   $tempQuestion= ['questions_text'];//update the $tempQuestion
}
```